# Sub Navigation Bar on hover below main navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, nav

I want to create a sub navigation bar using bootstrap that look as in the image below. For example, the 'Advertising' tab on the main nav bar can have two sub pages named 'How It Works' and 'Our Partners'. I want the 'How It Works' and 'Our Partners' links to be shown in a subnav bar below the main nav bar when the mouse is hovered on the 'Advertising' tab. How can I do this? Tried so many examples online, but still couldn't get it working

[image]

Comment: Please give an example of the code you try in a fiddle for example and then we can help you easily :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

***I used bootstrap V3.3.6***

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/pfss9b28/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="navbar">    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Advertising <b class="caret"></b></a> 

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">How It Works</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Partners</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                 <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Test other child <b class="caret"></b></a> 

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">child 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">child 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">child 3</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#">child 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">child 5</a></li>                            
                    </ul>
                </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.navbar-default{
  background:#333;
  color:#fff;
} 

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a{
    color:#fff !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover{text-decoration:underline}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown > a{position:relative;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown:hover > a:after{
    background: #333;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
    left: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    margin-top:-10px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 15px;
    z-index:10001;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover{background:#333;color:#fff;text-decoration:underline;}
.nav > li{
    position:inherit;
} 
.dropdown-menu{
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100% !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    right: 0;
    background:#E1E0DE;
    padding:13px 0px;
}

.dropdown-menu > li{
    display:inline-block;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background:#E1E0DE;
}  
ul.nav li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: How can I attach the content of the subnav to start from where the arrow is? For example, how can I make "How It Works" under "Advertising" start from where the arrow head is?

Comment: @YohanBlake you can use JavaScript ** Example :  ** https://jsfiddle.net/pfss9b28/3/

Comment: You're the best :D